# Inserting data into an SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've execute this code in Android for inserting 100+ rows in SQLite database.
My current approach takes more time to initialize the database.

```
private void getInitialization() {
    try {
        dao = new IdentifyImageDao(MainActivity.this);
        dao.open();
        level = new Level();

        for (int i = 0; i < Level.LEVEL_NO_ARRAY.length; i++) {

            level.setLevelNo(Level.LEVEL_NO_ARRAY[i]);
            level.setTotalGuess(0);
            level.setTotalImages(Level.TOTAL_IMAGES_PER_LEVEL[i]);
            if (i < 2)
                level.setLevelStatus(Level.LEVEL_UNLOCK);
            else
                level.setLevelStatus(Level.LEVEL_LOCK);
            dao.insertLevel(level);
        }

        images = new Images();
        // IMAGES_ID.length = 150
        for ( int i = 0; i < Images.IMAGES_ID.length; i++ ) {
            images.setLogoId(Images.IMAGES_ID[i]);
            images.setLogoCheck(Images.IMAGE_UNCHECK);
            dao.insertImages(images);
        }
        dao.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Database method for image insertion

```
public long insertImages(Images images) throws SQLException {
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put(LOGO_NO, images.getLogoId());
    value.put(LOGO_CHEECK, images.getLogoCheck());
    return database.insert(TABLE_LOGO_MASTER, null, value);
}
```

Please review my code and suggest a more efficient and faster approach for inserting multiple data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void getInitialization()`

- The name of the method implies that we would get something but the return value is `void`. Maybe a better name would be in order. How about `Initialize()` ?
- an empty `catch` block is always a very bad sign. If you want to swallow any exception, you should clearly state with a comment **why** you are swallowing the exceptions.
- it is always recommended to use braces `{}` for single statment `if` to make the code less error prone.
- `images = new Images();` where is `images` declared ? It would be better to have this as a method scoped variable instead of reusing a class level one.

  In addition the name `Images` implies that it contains multiple `Image` items which it doesn't do.
- If an exception is thrown from inside the `try` block after the call to  `dao.open();` the `dao` will stay open.

  You should use a `finally` block to close the `dao`.

Comment: thanks sir for your valuable suggestion i follow your suggestion

Comment: please guide me more for improve data inserting speed in database my current logic take more time for inserting data. What there are any faster approach for same task then i increase my code efficiency

Comment: Without seeing the code of `IdentifyImageDao` and `database.insert()` it is hard to tell how to speed things up. If you think about editing your question to inc these details make sure to **not** invalidate the givven answer, otherwise the edit will be rolled back.

Comment: sir in code i have declare insertImage() method for insert image id and there lock status in database. This method insert image one by one in database, it's calling in getInitialization() with in loop and loop iterate till length of Array (containing images id).

Comment: Then I need to say that without any new code this is as fast as it can get.

Comment: then sir what i have option to paste that code 1 in new Ques or Edit it.

Comment: I would create a new question, adding the dao code and also show what the `database` is. If `database` is not a library class you should show the code too.